# How to add a unique constraint which complex conditions in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

There is a table t1. It has a uuid field (which cannot be made primary key) and a deleted_ts field.
Whenever a new record is going to be added, we should check if "select count(1) from t1 where uuid = [recourd.uuid] and deleted_ts is not null" is 0 or not. If it is not 0, the record should not be added.
The same thing should be done when updating an record.

I think I should use constraint or trigger... but I have investigated it for a while but still don't know how to do it. Any suggestion?

Comment: you need a trigger.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Can you please give me an example on how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this be OK?

```
SQL> create table test (uuid number, deleted_ts number, name varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_biu_test
  2    before insert or update on test
  3    for each row
  4  declare
  5    l_cnt number;
  6  begin
  7    select count(*) into l_cnt
  8      from test
  9      where uuid = :new.uuid
 10        and deleted_ts is not null;
 11    if l_cnt > 0 then
 12       raise_application_error(-20000, 'Error - uniqueness violated');
 13    end if;
 14  end;
 15  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing (read comments):

```
SQL> -- OK, first row ever
SQL> insert into test values (1, null, 'a');

1 row created.

SQL> -- OK, as there's no row with a non-empty DELETED_TS
SQL> insert into test values (1, null, 'b');

1 row created.

SQL> -- OK, as this is the first non-empty DELETED_TS for UUID = 1
SQL> insert into test values (1, 100, 'c');

1 row created.

SQL> -- Error, as this is the 2nd non-empty DELETED_TS for UUID = 1
SQL> insert into test values (1, 200, 'd');
insert into test values (1, 200, 'd')
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: Error - uniqueness violated
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TRG_BIU_TEST", line 9
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.TRG_BIU_TEST'


SQL> -- OK, as this is the first non-empty DELETED_TS for UUID = 2
SQL> insert into test values (2, 300, 'e');

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Comment: If you use this sort of trigger and do an `insert select` statement to insert multiple rows, the trigger will throw a mutating table exception.  You'd need a compound trigger to avoid that and some additional locking mechanism if you wanted to deal with transaction control issues.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want a unique function-based index

```
create unique index idx_uuid_uniq_or_del
    on t1( case when deleted_ts is not null
                then uuid
                else null
             end );
```

Note that your description seems odd to me.  You seem to want to allow multiple "live" rows with the same `uuid` value but only one "deleted" row with that value.  Normally, it would be the reverse-- you want to ensure that there is only one "live" row per `uuid` while allowing multiple deleted rows.  If that's really what you want

```
create unique index idx_one_live_uuid
    on t1( case when deleted_ts is null
                then uuid
                else null
             end );
```

If you try to use a single trigger like @Littlefoot shows, that will work so long as you only ever do single-row `insert ... values` statements.  As soon as someone comes along and does a multi-row insert (i.e. an `insert ... select`)

```
insert into test( uuid, deleted_ts, name )
  select 2, null, 'a' from dual union all
  select 2, null, 'b' from dual union all
  select 2, 100, 'c' from dual;
```

the trigger will throw a mutating table exception.  You could have a compound trigger with row- and statement-level sections (or a combination of row- and statement-level triggers) to get around the mutating table exception but you'd still have transaction control issues where two sessions are making changes that together violate your rule but neither session can see the violation because they can't see the other session's uncommitted changes.  You could work around those transaction control issues by adding some additional locking but now we're getting into a pretty complicated bit of code that is going to be relatively easy for you (or some future developer) to make a mistake in and/or create support or scalability issues.  A function-based unique index is much simpler and takes care of these issues automatically.